# How to represent number n (assume base 10) using x bits?

Tags: algorithm, math

I need to represent a number `n` using ONLY `x` bits. Usually, I can choose the suitable base, and find the number of digits needed. But here my constraint is that I have only 'x' bits available. I can have more 1 set of 'x' bits, however.

I am trying to understand about how numbers can be represented in any given system like this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understood your problem correctly, but assuming you have a natural number x that can be represented with m (e.g., 20) bits, but you have only arrays of n bits at your disposal (say, bytes, i.e. 8-bit arrays), the amount of arrays you need is simply m/n rounded up to the next natural number. For a number that has 20 digits in binary format, that would be 3 bytes.

E.g. if your number is

```
1001 01101100 10110100,
```

you could store it as

```
00001001

01101100

10110100.
```

What you have done is to

1. (integer-) divide your number by 100000000 (10^1000, or 2^8 in decimal system), write down the remainder, truncate the result
2. (integer-) divide the result of 1. by 100000000, write down the remainder, truncate the result
3. (integer-) divide the result of 2. by 100000000, write down the remainder, truncate the result
4. nothing interesting to do anymore because the result of 3 was 0.

Assuming we talk about natural numbers here, in the decimal system the above would look like this:

```
1. 617652/256 = 2412 remainder 180 (10110100 in binary system)

2.   2412/256 =    9 remainder 108 (01101100 in binary system)

3.      9/256 =    0 remainder   9 (00001101 in binary system)
```

So what you are doing is

```
while (number > 0) {
    divide number by 2^n
    remember remainder
    truncate number
}
```

Restoring the original number is left as an exercise :)

This is actually a problem that comes up whenever you want to deal with very large integer numbers on the computer. I guess a good place to start looking for further information might be http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positional_notation.